# Timing issues Psychopy PyGaze EyeTribe Eyetracker (Multithreading)

Tags: multithreading, psychopy, eye-tracking

I have an experiment in which I present stimuli using PsychoPy / PyGaze and track eye movements with an EyeTribe eye tracker. In this experiment I update the size of two visual stimuli on each frame (at 60 Hz). I prepare each frame beforehand and afterwards loop through all of the screen objects and present them. Meanwhile, a continuous sound is playing. When I run this experiment in dummy mode (mouse movement is used as a simulation for gaze position), there are no timing issues for the visual presentation. However, when I run the experiment while performing eye tracking, the timing of the visual presentation is no longer accurate (higher variability in duration of frames).

I tried looking into the multi threading more, but in the pytribe script of PyGaze I can't find any evidence that one thread is waiting for an event coming from the eye tracking thread. So, I have no idea how to figure out what is causing the timing issues or how to solve this? (I hope I explained the problem sufficiently specific).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worse than just needing a separate thread for eyetrack versus stimulus rendering. What you really need is a separate *process* that avoids the python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). The GIL prevents different threads from running on different processors.

For improved temporal precision I would really recommend you switch from pygaze to iohub (which also has support for eyetribe I believe). iohub does run genuinely on a different core of the machine where possible so that your stimuli and eye data can be processed independently in time, and it handles all the sync stuff for you.

Comment: Dear Jon. Thanks for the answer. I ran your timeByFrames demo with and without eye tracking using iohub. Without eye tracking I get an average frame rate of 16.7 ms (SD = 1.29) and 0.4 % dropped frames, while I get an average of 13.6 ms (SD = 2.18) with 2 % dropped frames with eye tracking. My CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU 2.30 GHz. How can the timing of the visual presentation go faster than the refresh rate of my monitor? Is the vertical blank interval blocking influenced by the eye tracking process in any way?

Comment: I'm just adding this comment if anyone would ever bump into the same issues. The timing of the visual presentation is good with iohub if I run my script from command prompt instead of Spyder.

Comment: Thanks for the info Hanne. I was always a bit worried that spyder would be slowign things down for people because it (presumably) has various additional things running to enable debugging. 
By the way, if the answer above works for you, could you mark it as answered/correct? cheers

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jon's answer: Hanne also emailed about the problem, and it turns out she was running her experiments from Spyder. When run from the command prompt, there shouldn't be any timing issues. (Obviously, the GIL is still around, but in practice this doesn't seem to affect screen timing.)

To prevent any issues in the future, I've added a class that allows for running the EyeTribe in a parallel Process. See: https://github.com/esdalmaijer/PyTribe/blob/master/pytribe.py#L365

Example use:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    from pygaze.display import Display
    from pygaze.screen import Screen
    from pytribe import ParallelEyeTribe

    disp = Display()

    scr = Screen()
    scr.draw_fixation(fixtype='cross')

    tracker = ParallelEyeTribe()


    tracker.start_recording()

    disp.fill(scr)
    disp.show()
    tracker.log("Stimulus onset")

    time.sleep(10)

    disp.show()
    tracker.log("Stimulus offset")
    tracker.stop_recording()

    tracker.close()
    disp.close()
```